# Push Object inside an Object using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a Class as below.

```
public class ProjectConfigModel
{
    ProjectDetailModel MCRIDInfo { get; set; }
    List<string> DoorsPaths { get; set; }
    public List<string> TrackNReleasePrjName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ProjectProxies { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This class object i need to fill using Jquery and pass it to my controller.

```
public JsonResult ConfigureProject(ProjectConfigModel PrjConfigObj)
{
}
```

Below is the method i am filling the object using Jquery.

```
        function onFinishCallback(onSucess, onError)
        {
            var ProjectInfo = {};
            var MCRIDInfo = {};
            MCRIDInfo["MCRID"] = $("#LBL_McrID_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["ProjectName"] = $("#LBL_ProjName_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["ProgramID"] = $("#LBL_PID_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["Division"] = $("#LBL_Division_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["ProjectManager"] = $("#LBL_PJM_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["Generation"] = $("#LBL_Gen_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["Region"] = $("#LBL_Region_Summry").text();
            MCRIDInfo["ProjectType"] = $("#LBL_McrID_Summry").text;
            MCRIDInfo["BusinessUnit"] = $("#LBL_McrID_Summry").text;
            MCRIDInfo["ProductClass"] = $("#LBL_McrID_Summry").text;
            ProjectInfo.push(MCRIDInfo);
          //  $.extend(ProjectInfo, MCRIDInfo);

            var DoorsPaths = $("#TA_DorsPath_Summry").text().split(';');
            var TrackNReleasePrjName = $("#TA_TRPrjName_Summry").text().split(';');
            var ProjectProxies = $("#TA_GrantAccess_Summry").text().split(';');
            var Comments = $("#TA_Comments_Summry").text();

            ProjectInfo.push(DoorsPaths);
            ProjectInfo.push(TrackNReleasePrjName);
            ProjectInfo.push(ProjectProxies);
            ProjectInfo.push(Comments);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl() + "/ProjectConfiguration/ConfigureProject",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "PrjConfigObj": ProjectInfo }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (JsonData) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (retVal) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        }
```

Above code data is not retrieved in my Controller. It is comming as null for all the fields.

How to Push objects inside an object?
How to add list values to object?

Comment: `push()` method adds new items to the end of an **array**

Comment: You data needs to be in the format `ProjectInfo = { MCRIDInfo: { MCRID: xx, ProjectName: xx, ... }, DoorsPaths: [ 'xx', 'yy' ], TrackNReleasePrjName: [ 'xx', 'yy' ], ... };`

Comment: How to create it in my scenario?

Comment: Its not clear what the point of this is - the data you are using is based on `.text()` meaning its not editable values, therefore it looks like you are just posting back the same data you just sent to the view

Comment: And it would be just `var ProjectInfo = { MCRIDInfo: MCRIDInfo, DoorsPaths DoorsPaths, TrackNReleasePrjName: TrackNReleasePrjName, ProjectProxies: ProjectProxies, Comments: Comments };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i needed to assign data to nested object is as follows:

```
                var ProjectInfo = {};
                var MCRIDInfo = {};
                MCRIDInfo["MCRID"] = $("#LBL_McrID_Summry").text();
                MCRIDInfo["ProjectName"] = $("#LBL_ProjName_Summry").text();
                MCRIDInfo["ProgramID"] = $("#LBL_PID_Summry").text();
                MCRIDInfo["Division"] = $("#LBL_Division_Summry").text();
                MCRIDInfo["ProjectManager"] = $("#LBL_PJM_Summry").text();
                MCRIDInfo["Generation"] = $("#LBL_Gen_Summry").text();               

                var DoorsPaths = $("#TA_DorsPath_Summry").text().split(';');
                var TrackNReleasePrjName = $("#TA_TRPrjName_Summry").text().split(';');
                var ProjectProxies = $("#TA_GrantAccess_Summry").text().split(';');
                var Comments = $("#TA_Comments_Summry").text();

                ProjectInfo["MCRIDInfo"] = MCRIDInfo;
                ProjectInfo["DoorsPaths"] = DoorsPaths;
                ProjectInfo["TrackNReleasePrjName"] = TrackNReleasePrjName;
                ProjectInfo["ProjectProxies"] = ProjectProxies;
                ProjectInfo["Comments"] = Comments;
```

Note : Name of the object Parameters should be same as the Modal class attribute name.